# Run a method as the service user

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, impersonation

I have a windows service that runs as a domain service account. The service self hosts a WCF service so that a client can connect(i.e the client described below).
I have a client application that runs as the logged in user on the same PC. The logged in user has only user privileges. The client contains a WCF client. Can i impersonate the domain service account that the service runs under using a WCF method(returning some token etc) or is this possible  that would then allow me to run some administrator commands on the PC (browsing,WMI queries etc)?

By the way i do know how to impersonate a user on the client application but i want to impersonate the service account without having to store the password.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is the opposite to what i want to do

Comment: I have implemented a lot of services doing exactly what you are hoping to accomplish. The only pitfall I encounter so far is that sometimes I assume that the service account is an admin account, which is not. And sometimes, if you are just trying to establish a proof of concept, the theory instantly fails because of this confusion. If you hit this wall, try using a real admin account and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @user3439376 i control the account that the user runs under on the service so that will not be a problem. could you post the code to achieve the solution?